# Any databases with CEO letters and shareholder letters?

Tags: reference-request, data-request

I am doing a research with content analysis, verifying certain disclosures on CEO letters and Shareholder letters present in annual reports of listed companies in the London Stock Exchange.

Can someone recommend a database where these letters would be available in plain text? Or at least where all the PDFs could be downloaded as a whole package? All I've found until now was the website [AnnualReports](http://www.annualreports.com/Companies?exch=9) but I believe someone must have done already this work :)

Comment: After several months I've found this link: https://www.icaew.com/library/company-research/company-reports-and-profiles/annual-reports
It's not a searchable-database with plain text, but it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like the Bloomberg Terminal; I hear they have a lot of information.

If you were looking for annual reports from American companies, I'd tell you to go to the SEC website. However, I've noticed that http://www.luse.co.zm/ has some annual reports from companies on the London Stock Exchange, such as British American Tobacco, [here](http://www.luse.co.zm/media/pdf/British-American-Tobacco-Annual-Report-2016_voChix1.pdf).